# django when to set session after login

Tags: django

I want to set the rights of my user in the session after a successfull login. For now I'm doing it in the view to which the user is redirected by default after the login. But this does not work if the user navigates directly to a view, logging in and passing the default view.

Where do I have to place a initial session setting, ensuring that it is always set?

I'm using djangos build-in login.

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html', }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece of middleware is probably your best bet - just have it check for whatever you're storing your permissions in, and then initialize it if the user is authenticated and it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: hmm.. never wrote a middleware before. Have to dig into it. Might be a good idea..

Comment: Thanks Luke. You are right. It works as you proposed. Just add a process_request in the new middleware, setting the session if not set before, and return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use decorators on each view like `@login_required` so you ensure that your user is logged in each view... Regards

Comment: This would just check whether my user is logged in. But I want to access in each template the specific rights of the logged in user without passing this information in the context of each request. Just want to place it once in the session.

Comment: so you whant to check the user permission with the template tags right ?  does this help :     http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator

Comment: this is still on view level. I just want to set the user rights once in the session and then in all templates I just check the permissions directly from the session. As luke proposed a middleware does the trick.